# Graceful shutdown of applications/servers

Tags: go

I am trying to find out if there is any difference between two implementations that currently do the same thing - gracefully shutdown applications/servers, for example, when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is hit. Both work fine and are based on the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Shutdown).

What a friend of mine says, is that Example 2 handles shutdown at the application level which shuts down all contexts throughout the application. However, Example 1 does it at the HTTP server level which doesn't necessarily shut down all contexts throughout the application. Since I am a beginner I cannot argue back and need your input on this, please.

**Example 1**

The signals are handled in the http.go file so the whole graceful shutdown has been handled in a single file.

**cmd/app/main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "internal/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    // Bootstrap config, logger, etc

    http.Start()
}
```

**internal/http/server.go**

```
package http


import (
    "context"
    "github.com/prometheus/common/log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func Start() {
    log.Infof("starting HTTP server")

    srv := &http.Server{Addr: ":8080", Handler: nil}

    idle := make(chan struct{})

    go shutdown(srv, idle)

    if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        log.Fatalf("failed to start/close HTTP server [%v]", err)
    }

    <-idle

    log.Info("gracefully shutdown HTTP server")
}

func shutdown(srv *http.Server, idle chan<- struct{}) {
    sig := make(chan os.Signal, 1)

    signal.Notify(sig, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    <-sig

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Duration(10)*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    if err := srv.Shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("shutdown HTTP server by interrupting idle connections [%v]", err)
    }

    close(idle)
}
```

**Example 2**

The signals are handled in the application's main.go file so the whole graceful shutdown has been split within two files. The only addition is this example uses the `WithCancel` context.

**cmd/app/main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "internal/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    // Bootstrap config, logger, etc

    backgroundCtx := context.Background()
    withCancelCtx, cancel := context.WithCancel(backgroundCtx)
    go shutdown(cancel)

    http.Start(withCancelCtx)
}

func shutdown(cancel context.CancelFunc) {
    sig := make(chan os.Signal, 1)

    signal.Notify(sig, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    <-sig

    cancel()
}
```

**internal/http/server.go**

```
package http

import (
    "context"
    "github.com/prometheus/common/log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func Start(ctx context.Context) {
    log.Infof("starting HTTP server")

    srv := &http.Server{Addr: ":8080", Handler: nil}

    idle := make(chan struct{})

    go shutdown(ctx, srv, idle)

    if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        log.Fatalf("failed to start/close HTTP server [%v]", err)
    }

    <-idle

    log.Info("gracefully shutdown HTTP server")
}

func shutdown(ctx context.Context, srv *http.Server, idle chan struct{}) {
    <-ctx.Done()

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Duration(10)*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    if err := srv.Shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("shutdown HTTP server by interrupting idle connections [%v]", err)
    }

    close(idle)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to be helpful to others who might be interested in the final outcome after many R&D days and suggestions from other forum users so on., this is what I ended up with. I hope it helps and comments are welcome.

**cmd/myself/main.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"

    "myself/internal/app"
)

func main() {
    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":8080",
        Handler: router.New(),
    }

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    signalChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)

    go handleSignal(signalChan, cancel)

    if err := app.New(srv).Start(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Info("shutdown complete")
}

func handleSignal(signalChan chan os.Signal, cancel context.CancelFunc) {
    // os.Interrupt: Ctrl-C
    // syscall.SIGTERM: kill PID, docker stop, docker down
    signal.Notify(signalChan, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    sig := <-signalChan

    log.Infof("shutdown started with %v signal", sig)

    cancel()
}
```

**internal/app/mysql.go**

````golang
package app

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type App struct {
    server  *http.Server
}

func New(srv *http.Server) App {
    return App{
        server:  srv,
    }
}

func (a App) Start(ctx context.Context) error {
    shutdownChan := make(chan struct{})

    go handleShutdown(ctx, shutdownChan, a)

    if err := a.server.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to start [%v]", err)
    }

    <-shutdownChan

    return nil
}

func handleShutdown(ctx context.Context, shutdownChan chan<- struct{}, a App) {
    <-ctx.Done()

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10 * time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    if err := a.server.Shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Infof("interrupted active connections [%v]", err)
    } else {
        log.Infof("served all active connections")
    }

    close(shutdownChan)
}

```
````

Comment: The shutdownChan is surprising to me. I would expect that ListenAndServe returns only after Shutdown is complete, but apparently this is not the case?

Comment: From godoc:  When Shutdown is called, Serve, ListenAndServe, and ListenAndServeTLS immediately return ErrServerClosed. Make sure the program doesn't exit and waits instead for Shutdown to return.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "magic" difference between solution 1 and 2. They do the same thing as of now. Both solution 1 and 2 react to Ctrl+C in the same way. The only difference is that by additionally using `ctx` in solution 2, you allow yet another possibility to trigger a graceful shutdown from software. For now, YAGNI, so I am reviewing the simpler solution 1.

The biggest mistake by far and the biggest lesson (for any language, not in any way Go specific): if you introduce a dependency such as "github.com/prometheus/common/log", make a cost-benefit calculation. Always. That is: if you need colorful logs, don't introduce 75 new packages to do that. One line turned a nice slim http server into a super-fragile behemoth. Specifically for Go 1.11+, you can see it here:

```
go mod init
cat go.mod
go build ./...
cat go.mod      # now populated 
go mod graph
   (prints one line per each module and version)
```

Also, I think that code becomes less complicated if you `Shutdown` in the main flow, and `ListenAndServe` in a goroutine? Take a look at my proposition:

```golang
package http // new line

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"

    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus" // resulting `go mod graph`  prints 7 modules
    // "log" // builtin without coloring - 0 modules
    //"github.com/prometheus/common/log"   // resulting `go mod graph`  prints 75 modules
)

func Start() {
    log.Infof("starting HTTP server")

    srv := &http.Server{Addr: ":8080", Handler: nil}

    go func() { // change
        if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            log.Fatalf("failed to start HTTP server: %v", err) // change
        }
    }()

    sig := make(chan os.Signal, 1)

    signal.Notify(sig, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    <-sig

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)  // change
    defer cancel()

    if err := srv.Shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("graceful shutdown of HTTP server: %v", err) // change
    }

    log.Info("gracefully shutdown HTTP server")
}
```

For **cmd/app/main.go** my only concern is to use fully qualified import path like "github.com/kubanczyk/myproj/internal/http" instead of `import "internal/http"`. There are dirty tricks to make short "internal/http" work for a short while, but I wouldn't recommend that. It's only intended for built-ins.